# ArcPy GPValueTable to get all domains in the GDB

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, domains

I write simple code using Python similar to AddCodedValueToDomain tool.
my tool works very well, but without the drop down menu to select fields from the geodatabase, so how I can allow the end user to select a domain from the specified field instead of writing it.

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.7

My Script:

```
import arcpy
inSDE = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
DomainaName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
DomainCode = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
DomainValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
arcpy.management.AddCodedValueToDomain(inSDE, DomainaName, DomainCode, DomainValue)
```

[image]

Comment: Add another parameter to your script interface of type _Field_ and make it _dependent_ on your table (in_SDE). Then you will be able to access the field in your script code

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407121/arcpy-gpvaluetable-to-get-all-domains-in-the-gdb#comment662327_407121):

> Add another parameter to your script interface of type *Field* and make
> it *dependent* on your table (in_SDE). Then you will be able to access
> the field in your script code.